# VBScript Array of Objects with properties vs parallel Arrays performance/memory

Tags: arrays, object, vbscript

In VBScript, would it be better (performance wise/memory wise) to use an array of ~100k objects (classes) with 10 properties each, or 10 parallel arrays (each representing a property of the object), or a multi-dimensional array. The size of the arrays is declared once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, the creation of 100k objects into an array will be ready under a second, unless you do some fancy (and time consuming things) in the `Class_Initialize` sub. The most important is to keep the initialization to a minimum. The creation of 10 arrays however will be instantly, but do not use `Redim (Preserve)` in each loop iteration, because each time a new array will be created and the values of the former one will be copied into the new one.

Memory wise, it would be better to create 10 arrays for the properties. An object instance takes more space on the heap (for internal methods/properties like typename, hash, etc.) than an array.

But working with 10 different arrays seems not a very smart design decision to me. Objects are flexible and expandable (you can use encapsulation and data validation ín the object itself). Do yourself and your coworkers a favour: Unless you are creating a piece of "once only software" (and why would you build that in the first place?), definately go for the object approach.